# Splitting CoreData up for a faster query time

Tags: iphone, sql, ios, sqlite, core-data

I have a **huge** core data database of longitudes and latitudes for paths on a map.

I have an object called a way which consists of an ordered set of Nodes (lon,lat).  I also store the enclosing box around the way (minLon, minLat, maxLon, maxLat ...).

[image: Data Model]

My query finds all the ways in a particular region of the map:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
    @"minLon < %f AND maxLon > %f AND minLat < %f AND maxLat > %f",
        maxLon, minLon, maxLat, minLat];
```

Its dam slow!

My idea to speed up the query is to split the data by square regions somehow (Multiple tables? Multiple `.sqllite` files? Create a hash of the location?) so there is less data to search though.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. You could speed up the query by storing the min/max values in your Way entity as scaled integers instead of floats. Pick a scaling factor that gives you an acceptable area resolution, use it to prescale the values when you store them and use the same scale factor when you do the query.
2. You could also look at adding a [quadtree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree) data structure to your core data model to home in on Ways in the desired area.
3. SQlite will bail out at the first test that fails in a compound predicate so put the cheapest test first.
4. Also look at enabling indexing for those 4 attributes.

To be honest though, I'm surprised that this is slow. How many total Ways do you have in your database and how many typically in an area that you want to query?

Have you tried turning on SQL debugging to see what query is actually run against the database? (hint: add -com.apple.CoreData.SQLDebug 1 as a command line argument in your Scheme editor for the Run behaviour)

Comment: Awesome idea.  Ill defiantly put that into practice.  My `.sqlite` file is 40MB. There are 700K nodes and 60K ways.  Its open street map data if you are interested.

Comment: Great suggestions. Iv not heard of indexing core data before, how do I do it/ What should I google? :)

Comment: In the Core Data model editor select an attribute and check the 'Indexed' option in the Core Data Inspector panel on the right hand side. This may or may not help - you will need to profile using the SQLDebug command line flag, which will display exactly how long each query takes. Indexing slows down inserts and increases db size but speeds up queries (theoretically).

Comment: To be honest, I think the quadtree solution is going to be the most effective and scaleable - but unfortunately also the hardest to implement.