# Save MKOverlay to Core Data

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data, mapkit, mkoverlay

I have an application that tracks a user and shows where they've been using `MKOverlay`. How can I save this information into Core Data so that when the user wants to see where they went yesterday they can load the map/overlay from Core Data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a similar project.  Mine is for cycle paths.  Here is how I structure my core data model:

[image]

I use an order parameter so I can work out how the points connect up.  But i think you can just check the 'ordered' property of the relationship now although im not entirely sure how it works.  The min / max attributes are for more efficient searches.  I store the lat long values as integers to save space after a suggestion to one of my [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7934623/what-is-the-approximate-resolution-of-a-single-precision-floating-point-number-w).  You might find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7908851/splitting-coredata-up-for-a-faster-query-time) useful too.

You probably want to add some attributes to the Way such as `Date`.

Comment: Thanks! I am very new to Core Data and don't understand the relationships and some other things. Where did you learn and where do you recommend looking? I have done several tutorials and I can save things without relationships just fine, but I want to make sure everything works as I need it to.

Comment: Found one and was able to figure it out. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can save any object in a core data model, but if they are not the default type like string, int, etc. you won't be able to query on them.

So you have to construct your entity with property that you will be able to query.

So I see 2 options, you save every information in an entity, but this way you will need to alloc again all objects.
Or you only save the property you will need to query and archive your object in a transformable or in a Binary Data property.

I don't know what would be best.